# 特定フォーマットのデータを辞書型で抽出したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

以下データフォーマットが出力されるログがあります。
そのログを辞書型で取得する方法はありますでしょうか？
色々試したりchatgptを利用しましたが適切な回答を得ることが出来ませんでした。

```
 1:call                             5:call-in           Grp: null
 2:call                             6:call-call          Grp: null
 3:call-dial   List: 1 DC: 94            7:call-dial   List: 4 DiC: 10
 4:call-dial   List: 1 DC: 95            8:callrelease
 9:call-work     ReaC: 6  Grop: null
10:call-work     ReaC: 9  Grop: null
```

取得したいイメージ

```
[
{1:"call"},
{2:"call"},
{3:"call-dial   List: 1 DC: 94"},
{4:"call-dial   List: 1 DC: 95"},
{5:"call-in           Grp: null"},
{7:"call-dial   List: 4 DiC: 10"},
{5:"call-in           Grp: null"},
{8:"callrelease"},
{9:"call-work     ReaC: 6  Grop: null"},
{10:"call-work     ReaC: 9  Grop: null"}
]
```

Comment: この程度の量なら ,,,,,} で省略せずに完全に書かないと、どういう仕様なのか伝わらないと思います。（例えば 7:call-dial List: 4 DiC: 10 は捨てていいのか? それとも ,,,の中に含まれているのか? ってなります）
「人間相手にわかるように説明できない」ことが問題点っぽいです

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。全くその通りですね。修正しました

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。ありがとうございました。

```
config_list = re.findall(r'(\d+):(.*?)(?=\s+\d+:|$)', config_date)
config_dict_list = [{key: value.strip()} for key, value in config_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

既に解決済みですが、`$` ではなく `\n` にすると `str.strip()` は不要になります。また、質問文にある「取得したいイメージ」では辞書のキーは整数型で、整数値としてソートされている様に見えます。(一部書き間違いの様な部分がありますが)

```py
config_list = re.findall(r'(\d+):(.*?)(?=\s+\d+:|\n)', config_date)
config_dict_list = sorted([{int(key): value} for key, value in config_list],
                          key=lambda x: [*x.keys()])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(config_dict_list)

# [{1: 'call'},
#  {2: 'call'},
#  {3: 'call-dial List: 1 DC: 94'},
#  {4: 'call-dial List: 1 DC: 95'},
#  {5: 'call-in Grp: null'},
#  {6: 'call-call Grp: null'},
#  {7: 'call-dial List: 4 DiC: 10'},
#  {8: 'callrelease'},
#  {9: 'call-work ReaC: 6 Grop: null'},
#  {10: 'call-work ReaC: 9 Grop: null'}]
```